# Array definition right after struct decalaration

Tags: c, struct

I have come across a rather unusual array definition immidieatly followed after a struct definition. I could not find any specific information about this. So can you please tell me what is going on here and what could be possible usage or advantages of such syntax/notation?

```
struct MAGIC {
    int a;
    char* b;
} magic[] = { //WHAT IS THIS LINE!?
    {0, "this is A"},
    {1, "this is B"}
};

int main()
{
    printf("0=>%d %s, 1=>%d %s\r\n",
    magic[0].a, magic[0].b,
    magic[1].a, magic[1].b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 0=>0 this is A, 1=>1 this is B

I have learned the structs are declared like this:

```
typedef struct MYSTRUCT {
 //members
} mystruct_t;
```

then I would create array:

```
mystruct_t s[] = { /* */ };
```

Comment: You need to get some basics tutorial on `struct` data type.

Comment: The output, is it not "0=>0 this is A, 1=>1 this is B" ?

Comment: @Pras yeah sorry was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array `magic` is declared that is of type `struct MAGIC` and it consists of two elements that are immediately initialized.

The array size is not explicitly specified; it is derived from the number of initializers. An advantage is that, should you later require other (initialized) elements, you can just provide the initializer and don't need to bother about adjusting  the array size specification.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, my point of surprise is why the line `} magic[] = {` can work? I mean what part of C standard allows such syntax

Comment: `}` is the termination of the struct type definition; `magic` is the name of a varible of that type; `[]` indicates it is an array, of yet unspecified size, and `{` is the opening brace of the initializers. These are all standard parts of declarations in C, combined into this specific declaration

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a separate `typedef` for the struct before declaring an object of that type.  The code you showed is exactly equivalent to:

```
struct MAGIC { int a; char *b; }; // define the struct type
struct MAGIC magic[] = { ... };   // create an array of that type.
```

C allows you to combine the struct definition with the declaration of the array; the struct definition is *complete* with the closing `}`, so from that point onward you can create instances of that type without needing to use a separate declaration statement.

You can do the same thing with non-array objects:

```
struct MAGIC { 
  int a;
  char *b;
} foo, // single instance of struct MAGIC,
  *bar, // pointer to instance of struct MAGIC,
  *bletch( void ); // function returning pointer to struct MAGIC
```

Granted, a many of us will argue that it's better style to separate the struct definition from the declarations, and to declare each instance separately:

```
struct MAGIC { 
  int a;
  char *b; 
};

struct MAGIC foo;
struct MAGIC *bar;
struct MAGIC *bletch( void );
```

etc.

You can use typedefs if you want to; some people think they make code clearer and easier to understand.  Personally, I feel that if the user of the type has to be aware of its "struct-ness" (IOW, has to access individual members), then it's better to *not* use a typedef - leave the "struct-ness" explicit.

Answer (score 0):

That one was doing something like below

```
struct MAGIC {
int a;
char* b;
};

int main()
{
   struct MAGIC magic[2];
   magic[0].a = 0;
   magic[0].b = "this is A";
   magic[1].a = 1;
   magic[1].b = "this is B";
   printf("0=>%d %s, 1=>%d %s\r\n",
   magic[0].a, magic[0].b,
   magic[1].a, magic[1].b);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Moving `struct MAGIC magic[2];` to be before `main()` would be a better representation of the original question's code.  Your code makes the `magic` array a local variable in `main()`.  In the original code, the `magic` array is a global variable.

Comment: Yes, you can also make that magic variable global. If you want you can move that magic variable declaration above the main method.